# Vue.js link redirection to external site

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue.js and I am trying to solve the following issue.

I have a component which look as follows:

```
<template>
   <div class="capture-photo">

   <input id="chooseFile"
     type="file"
      accept="image/*"
      capture="environment"
      @change="onImageCaptured($event.target.name, 
      $event.target.files)">

   <div v-show="imgURL">
    <img v-bind:src="imgURL"  style="width:200px">
    <button id="sendImage" v-on:click.prevent="post">Send Image</button>

  <div id="extractedLink">
    <a id="extractedLinkButton" v-bind:href="urlLink">{{ urlLink }}</a>
  </div>


  </div>
```

and I am trying to run a test that would check that the link is clicked and redirects to the correct page (the urlLink is defines in the `data` element of my component. The testing in done using nightwatch and the test code looks like this:

```
'Redirect the extracted url to the actual website': function test(browser) {
    const devServer = browser.globals.devServerURL;

    browser
      .url(devServer)
      .waitForElementVisible('#app', 5000)
      .click('input[id="chooseFile"]')
      .setValue('input[type="file"]', require('path').resolve('http://www.coolture.pt/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/nos-alive-18-3.jpg'))
      .click("#sendImage")
      .assert.elementPresent('#extractedLink', 'http://nosalive.com')
      .assert.elementPresent("#extractedLinkButton")
      .click("#extractedLinkButton")
      .assert.urlEquals('http://nosalive.com')
      .end();
  },`
```

when running the test, the error message that I receive is the following:

```
TEST FAILURE:  1 assertions failed, 35 passed. (38.623s)

 ✖ capturePhoto

   - Redirect the extracted url to the actual website (2.8s)
   Testing if the URL equals "http://nosalive.com".  - expected "http://nosalive.com" but got: "http://localhost:8081/#/"`
```

where http://nosalive.com, being the urlLink value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you
N

Comment: I'm suspecting that the test finishes executing before Vue can update the DOM. How is `urlLink` defined in your Vue instance? Maybe try adding `.pause(1000)` between `.click("#extractedLinkButton")` and `.assert.urlEquals('http://nosalive.com')`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have already done this and unfortunately and it does not.

Comment: I will try console logging each step of the test and see what happens at each step.